# How to pass a Java string array []String to Go via cgo/JNA

Tags: java, c, go, jna, cgo

I would like to pass a String[] in Java to my Go function via JNA.

My go function has the following signature:

```
func PredicateEval(keys, values []string, expression string) *C.char
```

I have compiled the go library with link mode as "c-shared". I have a *GoString* in java defined as:

```
package predicates;
import com.ochafik.lang.jnaerator.runtime.NativeSize;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * <i>native declaration : coverage_server/predicate_jvm_bridge/lib/libtest.h</i><br>
 * This file was autogenerated by <a href="http://jnaerator.googlecode.com/">JNAerator</a>,<br>
 * a tool written by <a href="http://ochafik.com/">Olivier Chafik</a> that <a href="http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CreditsAndLicense">uses a few opensource projects.</a>.<br>
 * For help, please visit <a href="http://nativelibs4java.googlecode.com/">NativeLibs4Java</a> , <a href="http://rococoa.dev.java.net/">Rococoa</a>, or <a href="http://jna.dev.java.net/">JNA</a>.
 */
public class _GoString_ extends Structure {
    /** C type : const char* */
    public Pointer p;
    public NativeSize n;
    public _GoString_() {
        super();
    }
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("p", "n");
    }
    /** @param p C type : const char* */
    public _GoString_(Pointer p, NativeSize n) {
        super();
        this.p = p;
        this.n = n;
    }
    public static class ByReference extends _GoString_ implements Structure.ByReference {
        
    };
    public static class ByValue extends _GoString_ implements Structure.ByValue {
        
    };
}
```

I also have a Go slice defined as:

```
package predicates;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * <i>native declaration : coverage_server/predicate_jvm_bridge/lib/libtest.h</i><br>
 * This file was autogenerated by <a href="http://jnaerator.googlecode.com/">JNAerator</a>,<br>
 * a tool written by <a href="http://ochafik.com/">Olivier Chafik</a> that <a href="http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/wiki/CreditsAndLicense">uses a few opensource projects.</a>.<br>
 * For help, please visit <a href="http://nativelibs4java.googlecode.com/">NativeLibs4Java</a> , <a href="http://rococoa.dev.java.net/">Rococoa</a>, or <a href="http://jna.dev.java.net/">JNA</a>.
 */
public class GoSlice extends Structure {
    /** C type : void* */
    public Pointer data;
    /** C type : GoInt */
    public long len;
    /** C type : GoInt */
    public long cap;
    public GoSlice() {
        super();
    }
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("data", "len", "cap");
    }
    /**
     * @param data C type : void*<br>
     * @param len C type : GoInt<br>
     * @param cap C type : GoInt
     */
    public GoSlice(Pointer data, long len, long cap) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.len = len;
        this.cap = cap;
    }
    public static class ByReference extends GoSlice implements Structure.ByReference {
        
    };
    public static class ByValue extends GoSlice implements Structure.ByValue {
        
    };
}
```

This is my attempt to convert a Java []String to a Go string[].

```
  static {
    try {
      Field field = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      unsafe = (sun.misc.Unsafe) field.get(null);
      Class<?> clazz = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0).getClass();
      DIRECT_BYTE_BUFFER_ADDRESS_OFFSET = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address"));
      DIRECT_BYTE_BUFFER_CLASS = clazz;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  private static long getAddress(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    assert buffer.getClass() == DIRECT_BYTE_BUFFER_CLASS;
    return unsafe.getLong(buffer, DIRECT_BYTE_BUFFER_ADDRESS_OFFSET);
  }

  public static _GoString_.ByValue JavaStringToGo(String jstr) {
    try {
      byte[] bytes = jstr.getBytes("utf-8");
      //ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
      ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
      bb.put(bytes);
      Pointer p = new Pointer(getAddress(bb));
      _GoString_.ByValue value = new _GoString_.ByValue();

      value.n = new NativeSize(bytes.length);
      value.p = p;
      return value;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
  
  public static GoSlice.ByValue JavaStringArrayToGoStringSlice(String[] strings) {
    _GoString_.ByValue[] goStrings = new _GoString_.ByValue[strings.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
      goStrings[i] = JavaStringToGo(strings[i]);
    }

    Memory arr = new Memory(strings.length * Native.getNativeSize(_GoString_.class));
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(Native.getNativeSize(_GoString_.class));
      byte[] bytes = goStrings[0].getPointer().getByteArray(0, Native.getNativeSize(_GoString_.class));
      arr.write(i*Native.getNativeSize(_GoString_.class), bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    }
    GoSlice.ByValue slice = new GoSlice.ByValue();
    slice.data = arr;
    slice.len = strings.length;
    slice.cap = strings.length;

    return slice;
  }
```

Everything compiles, but when i try to access the slice elements on the Go side, i get a seg fault:

```
unexpected fault address 0xb01dfacedebac1e
fatal error: fault
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0xb01dfacedebac1e pc=0x10d7d3d6f]

goroutine 17 [running, locked to thread]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You're losing track (and control) of the memory allocation of the actual Strings.

Your mapping of `_GoString_` only includes allocation of a Pointer (4 or 8 bytes) and a `NativeSize` (a 4- or 8-byte `size_t`).  This mapping assumes the `Pointer` remains valid:

```java
public class _GoString_ extends Structure {
    /** C type : const char* */
    public Pointer p;
    public NativeSize n;
    // constructors, etc.
}
```

However, when you assign the value to `p` you only keep track of the pointer's address and not the actual memory allocation (I've added comments to your code):

```java
  public static _GoString_.ByValue JavaStringToGo(String jstr) {
    try {
      byte[] bytes = jstr.getBytes("utf-8");
      // 
      // Here you allocate memory for the bytes
      //
      ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes.length);
      bb.put(bytes);
      // 
      // Here you only keep track of the pointer to the bytes
      //
      Pointer p = new Pointer(getAddress(bb));
      // 
      // You never reference bb again, it is no longer reachable
      // and its allocation can be reclaimed by the system
      //
      _GoString_.ByValue value = new _GoString_.ByValue();

      value.n = new NativeSize(bytes.length);
      value.p = p;
      return value;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

As a direct bytebuffer, the memory location and (de)allocation mechanism are different than normal objects and GC, but the fundamental principle applies that once you've lost reference to the Java object (the `ByteBuffer`) you have no control over when that native memory will be freed.  (When `bb` is GC'd, its internal fields include the reference that will trigger the deallocation when it is processed.)

One possible solution is to add a `private` field to your `_GoString_` class that maintains a strong reference to the `ByteBuffer` and prevents the system from reclaiming its memory (possibly adding a `ByteBuffer` constrcutor).

Another solution is to use JNA's `Memory` class for the Strings and directly store that `Memory` object (which extends `Pointer`) to the `p` field.  I'm not sure why you have chosen direct byte buffers for this application, so this may not apply to your use case but it would certainly simplify your code.